# Drawing various types of shapes

Tags: object-oriented, c, polymorphism

I did the following Excercise:

> simulate single inheritance in C. Let each "base
>      class" contain a pointer to an array of pointers to functions (to simulate
>      virtual functions as freestanding functions taking a pointer to a "base
>      class" object as their first argument). Implement "derivation" by
>      making the "base class" the type of the first member of the derived class.
>
> For each class, initialize the array of "virtual functions" appropriately. To test the ideas, implement a version of "the old Shape example" with the base
>   and derived draw() just printing out the name of their class. Use only
>   language features and library facilities available in standard C.

I wonder if my approach is good? And as a side question: Is OOP relevant in practice with using c?

**Edit**: the goal is to simulate c++ like OOP constructs with the limited features of c.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void(*pfct)(struct Shape*);

typedef struct {
    pfct draw;
}Vtable;

typedef struct{                 // "Base class"
    Vtable* pvtable;
}Shape;

typedef struct{                 // "Derived" from Shape
    Shape shape;
    int radius;
}Circle;

void draw(Shape* this)          // "Virtual function"
{
    (this->pvtable->draw)(this);
}

void draw_shape(Shape* this)    
{
    printf("Drawing Shape\n");
}

void draw_circle(Shape* this)
{
    Circle* pcircle = (Circle*)this;
    printf("Drawing Circle with radius = %i\n",pcircle->radius);
}

Shape* init_shape()
{
    Shape* pshape = malloc(sizeof(Shape));
    Vtable* pvtable = malloc(sizeof(Vtable));
    pvtable->draw = &draw_shape;        
    pshape->pvtable = pvtable;
    return pshape;
}

Circle* init_circle(int radius)
{
    Circle* pcircle = malloc(sizeof(Circle));
    pcircle->shape = *init_shape();
    pcircle->shape.pvtable->draw = &draw_circle;
    pcircle->radius = radius;
    return pcircle;
}

int main()
{
    Shape* myshape = init_shape();
    Circle* mycircle = init_circle(5);
    draw(myshape);
    draw(mycircle);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think your exercise's explanation should be a little more.. explained. It isn't clear what you are supposed to achieve.

Comment: The exercise appears to be #21 in [Chapter 27](https://github.com/ChrisBKirov/Programming-Principles-and-Practice-Using-C-by-Bjarne-Stroustrup-/blob/master/README.md#chapter-27) of Bjarne's C++ book [Programming Principles and Practice Using C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/)

Comment: I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/197302/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Simulate single inheritance in c
>   I wonder if my approach is good?

### Function consistency

I'd expect `..._circle(Shape* this)` functions to take `Circle* this`.  Let the `draw()` play with the pointer conversions.

```
void draw(void* this) {
  Shape* pthis = this;
  (pthis->pvtable->draw)(pthis);
}

void draw_circle(Circle* this) {
    printf("Drawing Circle with radius = %i\n",this->radius);
}

// No longer generate a warning
draw(mycircle);
```

### Naming convention

For type `Shape`, code uses `..._shape`, the undefined `struct Shape` and  `Vtable`.  I'd expect greater uniformity - perhaps `Shape_init()`, `Shape_draw()`, `Shape_Vtable`, etc.

For `Circle`, use `Circle_draw()`, `Circle_init()`, etc. and not `..._circle()`.

Avoid text case changes.

### Avoid anonymous `struct Shape`

This problem hints that code is using C++ to compile C code.  Best to use C for C code.

Change `typedef void(*pfct)(struct Shape*);` to `typedef void(*pfct)(Shape*);` and move after `typedef struct{ ... }Shape;`

### Missing companion `free()`

A companion to `..._init()`, a `..._uninit()` should exist.

### Organization

Put `Shape` code in one place (or file) and `Circle` in another.

---

### Consider allocating to the object, not the type

It is easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// pshape = malloc(sizeof(Shape));
pshape = malloc(sizeof *pshape);
```

### Error checking

Robust code checks memory allocation.

```
pshape = malloc(sizeof(Shape));
if (pshape == NULL) Handle_OutOfMemory();
```